# After I installed UFW ssh login very slow

Tags: ssh, login, performance, ufw

I'm wondering if I made a mistake or if this is the normal case. I turned off password based ssh login and changed it to RSA key exchange. After that I changed the ssh port and then I installed UFW. I added ssh to UFW rules and turned UFW on. After that the login via ssh became very slow (>30 seconds). Before it was just some milliseconds. Is this normal or did I something wrong? I'm very new as ubuntu server admin. I hope you can help me to track down this issue.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem last night.

```
$ sudo ufw allow ssh
$ sudo ufw enable
```

Didn't affect my current `ssh` session, but it did cause a significant delay with `ssh` logins.  For example, an `ssh` login like below would hang for some period of time before (finally) prompting for a password:

```
$ ssh myusername@mydomain.com
$
```

(wait for 40 seconds or longer until...)

```
myusername@mydomain.com's password:
```

Of course, this delay would go away after disabling `ufw` with `$ sudo ufw disable`.

I have used `ufw` many times before and have never seen this problem.  At any rate, the issue has since disappeared and I can only assume that it is because I ran an `update` `upgrade` and `reboot` last night before heading to sleep.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't solve the issue for you, and there are packages being held back, then you might try `dist-upgrade`:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```